# SSRS How to change grouping and columns by using parameter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, reportbuilder3.0

My goul would be to implement a parameter @Grouping with two possibilities: Vendor / Product
With the parameter I need to change the grouping of my data, not only in calculateing the data but also in the sorting of the columns:
[image]

Do I need to use executable SQL and calculate everything outside the report and use dynamic columns like
 "Column1=Vendor, Column2=Product if Parameter=Vendor" to place them in the Tablix?

Or is it possible to manage all this in the report using grouping properties? If so, unfortunately I am not very familiar with the grouping expressins and would thank you for detailed answers.

Comment: Try this link: https://www.optimusinfo.com/blog/how-to-set-up-dynamic-grouping-in-ssrs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use the parameter :)
With Vendor beeing my default first Group, I made a Right-Click on the Group in the GroupingBox. In the General section I added an Expression on the "Group on":

```
=IIf(Parameters!Grouping.Value = "Vendor", Fields!Vendor.Value, Fields!Product.Value)
```

On the child group Product I did the opposit:

```
=IIf(Parameters!Grouping.Value = "Vendor", Fields!Product.Value, Fields!Vendor.Value)
```

The same expressions I used in the Sorting section. And also in the fields on the Tablix.
Thank you.